# Sub menu (expanded/collapsed tree) in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui

I have for the past day got stuck on finding the best way to use angular to control a menu list with sub-menus.

With jQuery you can just listen after a click event on a specific type of element like a `<li>` and add a class to its child element for a menu to open.

I'm trying to do the same thing like the menu on this page http://geedmo.com/themeforest/wintermin/dashboard.html, with Angular. But can't find the correct way by using my own directive or existing ones like ng-hide and ng-show.

If anyone have an example og guides on how to do this the best way, my day would be saved. :)

I'm also new to angular so learning new thing every day.

Comment: Hi Artyom, i'm trying to have my menulist with sub menus functioning as the menu on the site I referred to. When you click one menu link the list under it expands, if you click on a new element the old submenu closes and the new sub-menu expands. =)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the following code to create expanded/collapsed submenu on AngularJS.

I've attached [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/7638/) example for you.

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="item in items" ng-click="showChilds(item)">
            <span>{{item.name}}</span>
            <ul>
                <li ng-repeat="subItem in item.subItems" ng-show="item.active">
                    <span>---{{subItem.name}}</span>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Your JS controller:

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {    
    $scope.showChilds = function(item){
        item.active = !item.active;
    };

    $scope.items = [
        {
            name: "Item1",
            subItems: [
                {name: "SubItem1"},
                {name: "SubItem2"}
            ]
        },
        {
            name: "Item2",
            subItems: [
                {name: "SubItem3"},
                {name: "SubItem4"},
                {name: "SubItem5"}
            ]
        },
        {
            name: "Item3",
            subItems: [
                {name: "SubItem6"}
            ]
        }
    ];
};
```

**UPDATE:**

I've updated my post due to your comment about, that when we click on the new menu's item, the previous should be collapsed.

Small changes in the code.

New [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/7640/) with your need.

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="item in items" ng-click="showChilds($index)">
            <span>{{item.name}}</span>
            <ul>
                <li ng-repeat="subItem in item.subItems" ng-show="item.active">
                    <span>---{{subItem.name}}</span>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

You JS controller:

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {    
    $scope.showChilds = function(index){
        $scope.items[index].active = !$scope.items[index].active;
        collapseAnother(index);
    };

    var collapseAnother = function(index){
        for(var i=0; i<$scope.items.length; i++){
            if(i!=index){
                $scope.items[i].active = false;
            }
        }
    };

    $scope.items = [
       // items array the same with the previous example
    ];
};
```

Comment: Hi thanks for this example. I se that every example generate the list items form the controlller, but i have my list items static in the html. Also is there a good way to make the other list that are open to close, when a new list element is clicked. So that you only have one submenu open at a time. =)

Comment: @Bent, it's a bad idea for AngularJS application to create tabs/menu statically. You should generate all your menu's elements from controller or directive.

Comment: @Bent, please see my update about your comment. I hope, that it's what you need :)

Comment: Thanks for all comment, and great examples! =)