# Menu and different submenu on click

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to build a menu and a submenu in angular.
What I want to do is to have two arrays of objects
Menu

```
menu = [{name: 'Name1', link: '/link1'}, {name: 'Name2', link: '/link2'}]
submenu = [[{name: 'SubName1', link: '/Sublink1'}, {name: 'SubName1', link: '/sublink1'}],
[[{name: 'SubName2', link: '/Sublink2'}, {name: 'SubName2', link: '/sublink2'}]]
```

So when I click `Name1` the first array of `SubMenu` will be selected and when clicking `Name2` the second array will be selected.
How I can create two Directives one for the main menu and one for the second and be able to communicate between them on click. I have tried building this in a controller, I was able to select the submenu by using the `$index`, but the submenu can't be moved around as I like because it needs to be under the controller.

I finally managed to solve my problem here is the solution: http://jsfiddle.net/4kjjyL4s/4/

How can I improve my solution?

Answer (score 4):

Don't reinvent the wheel :) UI router is a prepackaged solution that handles nested routing for you.

If you have a menu of items and you want to display another menu of items when one of the items is selected UI router does exactly that. https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router

Answer (score 0):

Can't give you the exact answer because information is lacking, but for example if you're using the directives with different menu items at other places in your app, I'd recommend to pass the menu array from controller (ng-controller, not directive's controller) through directive's scope.

Also, you're looking for kinda standard way for directives to communicate directly (in your case, communication between menu and submenu directive to notify the item selection change), use directive's controller. Here's a good tutorial.

https://thinkster.io/egghead/directive-to-directive-communication/

Answer (score 0):

To communicate between controllers or directives, you should use **services**.

From the angular guide ( https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services ):

> Angular services are substitutable objects that are wired together using dependency injection (DI). You can use services to organize and share code across your app.

I checked the code you posted on jsfiddle ( http://jsfiddle.net/4kjjyL4s/4/ )and I tried to keep the most of it. Below are my changes in the JavaScript file ( please, read the comments in the code ).

```
var app = angular.module("app",[]);

app.controller('main', function(){});
// The service will be responsible for the shared objects and logic
app.service('MenuService', function () {
  var list = [
    {
      name: "Menu1", link: "#menu1", 
      submenu: [ 
        { name: "Menu1Sub1", link: "#submenu1" },
        { name: "Menu1Sub2", link: "#submenu2" }
      ]
    },
    {
      name: "Menu2", link: "#menu2",
      submenu: [
        { name: "Menu2Sub1", link: "#submenu1" }, 
        { name: "Menu2Sub2", link: "#submenu2" }
      ]
    }
  ];

  var selected = [];

  // methods and attributes published under the **this** 
  // keyword will be publicly available
  this.getMenu = function () {
    return list;
  };

  this.getSubmenu = function () {
    return selected;
  };

  this.select = function ( menuItem ) {
    // this does the *trick*!
    // if we use the assignment operator here,  we would replace the 
    // reference returned in the getSubmenu() method, so as the original 
    // reference did not change, angular's dirty checking would not detect it.
    // using angular.copy() method, we are copying the contents of the
    // selected submenu over the same reference returned by getSubmenu()
    angular.copy( menuItem.submenu, selected );
  };
});

// No $rootScope injection results in better re-usability. When you were
// relying in $rootScope sharing, both directives should live in the 
// $rootScope, so if you add them inside a ng-controller created scope
// they would not work anymore
app.directive("menu", function() {
  return {
    restrict: "E",

    // no need to isolate scope here, *scope:true* creates a new scope
    // which inherits from the current scope
    scope: true,

    // with controllerAs (introduced in angular 1.2), you can skip 
    // polluting the scope injection.
    controllerAs: "ctrl",
    controller: function( MenuService ) {
      this.list = MenuService.getMenu();
      this.changeSub = function ( menuItem ) { MenuService.select( menuItem ); };
    },
    template: "<div ng-repeat='menu in ctrl.list'><button ng-click='ctrl.changeSub(menu)'>{{menu.name}}</button></div>"
  };
});

app.directive("submenu", function() {
  return {
    restrict: "E",
    scope: true,
    controllerAs: "ctrl",
    controller: function( MenuService ) {
      this.sublist = MenuService.getSubmenu();
    },
    template: "<span ng-repeat='menu in ctrl.sublist'>{{menu.name}} | </span>aa"
  };
});
```

And here is the updated HTML file, just to show both directives work now not directly inserted in the `$rootScope`

```
<div ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="main">
        <menu></menu>
        <h1>Hello World!</h1>
        <div class="main-content">
            <submenu></submenu>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

**Try this Code:**

```
function MyCtrl ($scope) {
        $scope.subMenu = [];    // default is false

    $scope.toggleSubMenu = function (index) {
        $scope.subMenu[index] = !$scope.subMenu[index];
    };
}
```

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li ng-class="{active: subMenu[0]}"> <a href="#hello" ng-click="toggleSubMenu(0)">Name1</a>
        <ul>
            <li>test</li>
            <li>test</li>
            <li>test</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li ng-class="{active: subMenu[1]}"> <a href="#foo" ng-click="toggleSubMenu(1)">Name2</a>
        <ul>
            <li>bar</li>
            <li>bar</li>
            <li>bar</li>
        </ul>
    </li>

</ul>
```

Also Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26571175/sub-menu-expanded-collapsed-tree-in-angularjs)